# Почему не получается поиск по datagrid в wpf по нескольким полям

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть у меня коллекция выводится в датагрид, сделал поиск по коллекции, но  поиск работает только по одному полю, а например по первому и третьему полю, почему то не ищет или если я пишу в строке поиска только второе поле у записи, тоже не ищет, как можно  искать  по всем полям так и по каким то конкретным в датагриде.
Вот код использую MVVM

Data

```
 public class info
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string Expiriens { get; set; }
        public string Salary { get; set; }

        public static info[] GetData()
        {
            var rezult =new info[]
            {
                new info(){FName = "Иван",LName = "Иванов",Expiriens = "какой то опыт",Salary = "50000"},
                new info(){FName = "Jon",LName = "Doe",Expiriens = "какой то опыт",Salary = "50000"},
                new info(){FName = "Jack",LName = "Daniels",Expiriens = "какой то опыт",Salary = "50000"},
                new info(){FName = "Максим",LName = "Максимов",Expiriens = "какой то опыт",Salary = "50000"}

            };
            return rezult;
        }

        public info()
        {
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel1 : DependencyObject
    {

        // Свойство для вывода данных в датагрид

        public ICollectionView Data
        {
            get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(MainViewModel1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        // свойство строки поиcка данных
        public string FilterText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(FilterTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FilterTextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FilterText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FilterText", typeof(string), typeof(MainViewModel1), new PropertyMetadata("", FilterText_change));


        // метод, который запускается при изменении в строке поиска.
        private static void FilterText_change(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is MainViewModel1 current)
            {
                current.Data.Filter = null;
                current.Data.Filter = current.FilterResume;
            }
        }

        private bool FilterResume(object obj)
        {
            bool rezult = true;
            // проверяем, передали ли нам нужный обект нужногонам типа.
            info current = obj as info;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterText) && current != null && !current.FName.Contains(FilterText) && !current.Expiriens.Contains(FilterText))
            {
                rezult = false;
            }

            return rezult;
        }

        // команда для загрузки данных из базы данных
        public Comand CommandGetData
        {
            get
            {
                return new Comand(() =>
                {
                    // заполняю датагрид данными из базы
                    Data = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(info.GetData());
                    Data.Filter = FilterResume;

                });
            }

        }

        public MainViewModel1()
        {
        }
    }
```

View

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new MainViewModel1();

        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="poisk.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:poisk"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="252" Margin="52,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="671">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="184" Margin="10,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="651"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="534"/>
        </Grid>

        <Button Command="{Binding CommandGetData }" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="273,316,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="268"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте фильтр вот так:

```
private bool FilterResume(object obj)
{
    bool rezult = false;
    // проверяем, передали ли нам нужный обект нужногонам типа.
    info current = obj as info;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterText) || (current != null && (current.FName.Contains(FilterText) || current.LName.Contains(FilterText) || current.Expiriens.Contains(FilterText))))
    {
        rezult = true;
    }

    return rezult;
}
```

А по второму полю у вас не искало, т.к. вы его забыли в условии.